# Dynamics Crm 2016 show subgrid N:N relationship

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have an custom entity called 'account checks' that has a many to many relationship with the account entity. I would like to place a subgrid on the main account form which shows related 'account check' records . Out of the box, CRM does not support this. Does anyone know of a quick supported/unsupported way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but why do folks keep saying this isn't supported. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but if you set up an N:N relationship, you can give either of the entities in the relationship a custom label, and switch the dropdown from "Do not display" to "Use Custom Label". You only need to do this for the item you want to see in the subgrid.

Once you do this, you should see the custom label value in your subgrid design properties for "Entity" under the Data Source section.

HTH!

Comment: And remember to make the related entity searchable, otherwise it won't show up in the 'Entity' dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box CRM **does** support many to many subgrids.

Comment: Thanks James, I can only select my custom entity in the datasource for the subgrid if I choose "All Record Types". In this case, I would like to display related 'account checks' and not all account checks. Have I missed something?

Comment: Yes, I can view the related records when I have an account form open and select the custom entity from the account form menu.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever get to the bottom of this?  What reasons could it explain its absence from the list?

Comment: This was a while ago, however I think I ended up replacing the fetchxml via javascript. This is not the exact article I followed, but has the basic idea
https://joshimandarblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/crm-2015-applying-custom-fetchxml-to-a-subgrid-using-javascript/#comments